# Using Rouche to find zeros of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $P(z)=z^6+3z^4+z^2+z+9$, prove that all its zeros are contained in the annulus $1<|z|<2$, and find how many of them are in the first quadrant.

I have been able to prove that they are indeed in the given annulus by comparing to $Q(z)=9$ and $R(z)=z^6$.

However I'm having trouble finding how many are in the first quadrant. I tried using a quarter circle contour of radius 2 but haven't been able to find the right polynomial to use to compare.

In case you're wondering, I used this version of the theorem $|f(z)-g(z)|<|f(z)|$.

Comment: This may be rather delicate for Rouché because two of the zeros are very close to the imaginary axis (approximately $-0.0308023814083735 \pm 1.86201438213256 i$).